# GIMP: Tools Don't Work

Tags: gimp

Recently I did something in GIMP, and now no matter what image I open, (almost) none of the tools work.

I can't draw, I can't erase, I can't make a rectangle or fuzzy selection ... the Move tool is the only one that works, and even it only works if I enlarge the canvas to make room (I'm pretty sure I could move parts of the image "off screen").  Many (but not all of the tools) even have a little circle with a line through it when I try to use them.

I don't have any selection on these images, I *am* in RGB mode, I've tried adding layers, and I've tried a bunch of other fixes online that (similarly) didn't work.  I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Gimp.

Does anyone have any idea what I could have done to put GIMP into this useless mode?

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot of my GIMP.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Gimp UI showing the Layers list and the titlebar. Otherwise, [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-When-suddenly-nothing-works-anymore) and [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-getting-unstuck.html).

Comment: Screenshot added.  I checked everything on both of those lists, but none helped :(

Comment: Not visible but I assume you did "Select >None" (or it is grayed out). So given the screen shot above, if you click+drag the mouse across the picture, nothing happens when one would expect some erasure (or replacement with white)?

Comment: Correct (both about selecting None ... I even selected All and then None to be sure) and about nothing happening when I try and erase ... or make a rectangle selection, or move the image, or use any other tool.

Comment: If the paint tools (bucket/blend/brush/eraser/airbrush/pencil) don't work but the transform tools (scale/rotate/flip...) do, a possibility is that all channels are deselected in the Channels list. Otherwise no better idea than renaming [your profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/) to start fresh.

Comment: I go excited, because the scale/rotate/flip *does* work, and my channels *were* deselected ... but then I clicked all three and still nothing worked :(  But, then I followed your link, and just renamed my entire `~/.config/GIMP` folder, and when I restarted GIMP it made a new copy of that folder and ... now everything works!  Thanks so much for your help! Could I trouble you to summarize your comments in an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the paint tools (bucket/blend/brush/eraser/airbrush/pencil) don't work but the transform tools (scale/rotate/flip...) do, a possibility is that all channels are deselected in the Channels list (because paint operations only apply to the channels that are selected).

When nothing seems to work, it can be a problem with your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/). Reinstalling Gimp is rarely a solution because that will keep the profile and its data. So the good solution is to rename your profile, and start Gimp again. It will create a new profile from scratch which should normally be OK. You can then copy things (typically, assets: brushes, patterns...) from the previous profile if necessary.